# How to show a list due to list items checkboxes in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I have a beginner question, I have two list side by side, Every item in the first list has it own items in second list, I mean when I select an item in first list, It should shows me list/items that related to it in the second list. Items are static. How can I do that ? Is it good to use DOM properties to show or hide other items ?

```
<ul className="privilegesList">
    <li>Groups</li>
    <li>Reports</li>
    <li>Supports</li>
</ul>

<ul className="privilegesList subLists">
    <li><Checkbox label="Mobile Device Management"/></li>
    <li><Checkbox label="Drive and Docs"/></li>
    <li><Checkbox label="G-Mail"/></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "react way to do it" would be to keep in the component's state which privilegesList item is selected.

You can add onClick functions to your clickable elements and have these functions change the component's state

Your render should be conditional to that state property.
Check this page in the docs for more info on conditional rendering: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

for example:

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            selectedPrivileges: "groups"
        }
    }

    renderSubList() {
        switch (this.state.selectedPrivileges) {
            case "groups":
                return (
                    <ul className="privilegesList subLists">
                        <li><Checkbox label="Mobile Device Management" /></li>
                        <li><Checkbox label="Drive and Docs" /></li>
                        <li><Checkbox label="G-Mail" /></li>
                    </ul>
                )
            case "reports":
                return (
                    <ul className="privilegesList subLists">
                        <li><Checkbox label="A" /></li>
                        <li><Checkbox label="B" /></li>
                        <li><Checkbox label="C" /></li>
                    </ul>
                )
            case "supports":
                return (
                    <ul className="privilegesList subLists">
                        <li><Checkbox label="K" /></li>
                        <li><Checkbox label="L" /></li>
                        <li><Checkbox label="G" /></li>
                    </ul>
                )
            default:
                return (
                    <ul className="privilegesList subLists">
                        <li><Checkbox label="X" /></li>
                        <li><Checkbox label="Y" /></li>
                        <li><Checkbox label="Z" /></li>
                    </ul>
                )
        }

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ul className="privilegesList">
                    <li onClick={() => this.setState({ selectedPrivileges: "groups" })}>Groups</li>
                    <li onClick={() => this.setState({ selectedPrivileges: "reports" })} > Reports</li>
                    <li onClick={() => this.setState({ selectedPrivileges: "supports" })} > Supports</li>
                </ul>
                {this.renderSubList()}
            </div>

        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, But I don't use separate components for second list.

Comment: You don't have to. I'll write and example to show you how

Comment: There it is, you don't need a separate component. But it could be good practice to do so, depending on the complexity of your component

Comment: Thank you very much, Great help, Just little question, If user swtich between components for selecting different items, It doesn't uncheck other components items ?

Comment: It all depends on how you manage the state for the selected components. Do it similarly to how I did for the selectedPrivileges, such as an array or map of selected checkboxes and pass the boolean to the checkboxes from state when they are rendered

Comment: Thanks for your time and answering my questions.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the values are most probably going to come from the server, I would implement something like the following:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      currentMain: undefined,
      main: [{ id: 1, name: "Item 1" }, { id: 2, name: "Item 2" }],
      subs: [
        { id: 1, name: "Sub Item 1 of Item 2", parentId: 2 },
        { id: 2, name: "Sub Item 2 of Item 2", parentId: 2 },
        { id: 3, name: "Sub Item 1 of Item 1", parentId: 1 }
      ]
    };
  }

  handleMainClick(id, event) {
    this.setState({ currentMain: id });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {this.state.main.map(item => (
            <li
              key={item.id}
              onClick={this.handleMainClick.bind(this, item.id)}
            >
              {item.name}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
        <ul>
          {this.state.subs
            .filter(item => item.parentId === this.state.currentMain)
            .map(item => <li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li>)}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/42xv6jj0mw

**Explanation**: The "main" collection from the state is being rendered as the first list. Upon clicking on any of the items, the id of this item is saved in the state as **currentMain**. Since updating the state will cause a re-render, you can then filter the second list of items (this.state.subs) based on the currently selected main item.

Of course everything depends on the format the data is represented.